# Low resolution infrared calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, triangulation

I want to perform stereo calibration using two infrared cameras (FLIR). 
Unfortunately, the images have low resolution (80 x 60 ). I used a circle grid with lamps using a square size of 160 mm. The localization of each point is performed using the gravity center around each lamp and then I am using findCircleGrid to sort the imagePoint to the right order.

My calibration RMS result is 0.2 which is good (I think) and the baseline of 5.7 cm is almost the same in the physical measure.

But, when I use the calibration to triangulate points ( stereoRectify, undistortPoints ,  correctMatches), the results are very strange.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryizJ.png)

[The image with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U37UI.png)

I would like to know if there is a way to accurately calibrate cameras with low resolution, or if there is a way to detect more accurately imagePoint (Now I'm using gravity center to detect the position each lamp ).

After having got the 3 points (X, Y, Z) I project plot them. I also try to trace the plane which passes through these points :

[The 3D point reprojection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGcI3.png)

This is the projection of the 3D points in a plane (X, Y) :

[The plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDtwh.png)

Thanks !!!

Comment: Can't the bad result come from the very short baseline that you have?

Comment: I make a mistake it's 5,7 cm of baseline!
sorry

Comment: Can you show what the _strange results_ are?

Comment: I have just added the 3D points reprojection in the above text, given that I cannot add images in comments.

Comment: Sorry for slightly off-topic comment. Can you tell what FLIR camera model do you have and what kind of API do you use to obtain the thermal image. My experiences with FLIR customer support are not really great.

Comment: could you also include some explanation on what each image is?

Comment: @apalomer I have just edited.

Comment: @YannickZoetgnande, although I am not an expert, I do not think your calibration result is acceptable. While the points on your real (the one you hold) calibration pattern are more or less evenly distributed, I do not see this either in the [3D reprojected points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGcI3.png) nor on the [plane image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDtwh.png).

Comment: @apalomer but do you know a way to accurately detect points. I use FindCircleGrid plus the calculation of the gravity center around each point. I suspect that these bad results are linked to the fact my images have low resolution.Perhaps if I can detect more accurately the points the results will be improved.

Comment: One thing you can do is draw the detected circle and center of gravity using the [drawing functions](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) that OpenCV has implemented. This way you'll be able to see how good are your detections.